# Ruby string scan method removes unpaired characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a "telephone" column in a database table and I want to display it in groups of 2 numbers, no matter how the user inputs it.

However, if it's a phone number formed from an odd number(let's say 7), the seventh character disappears.

I have an after_create filter which does exactly this:

```
def phone_format
  self.telephone = "#{self.telephone.scan(/../).join(" ")}"
  binding.pry unless self.save
end
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please give example input and desired results.

Comment: Sure, for example, 4 9s would come off as: 99 99. But if the input consists of 5 9s, it would still come off as: 99 99 instead of 99 99 9.

Comment: What would be the correct grouping: `12 34 5` or `1 23 45`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/../` to `/.{1,2}/`, or better, `/\d{1,2}/`.

Comment: It works :) does this mean between 1 and 2 encounters of a digit?

Comment: mudasobwa, BogdanPopa: Yes.